# obtaining name of pdf

Tags: iphone, objective-c

thanks in advance 
i have application in which i download pdf as a attachment through email account like gmail.com and it will be saved in tableview as one static name like attachment all this is runnable 
now i want that during downloading of pdf i have to save with some name which is display in gmail account so how how can i do this i want to save that name which is show with attachment name like  compansionFishpdf- print

Answer (score 1):

When you download the PDF file, save it with that name. I usually pass a parameter "filename" from the server to the app when it downloads a file, but I don't know what kind of server language you're using.

Comment: give me syntax for passing parameter filename in objective-c lang